# C# ASP.NET MVC 5 -> ActionFilterAttribute -> Stop redirecting HTTP 401 automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the `System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute` below registered as a global filter. If the response is `400 BadRequest` the application works as expected but If I return `401 Unauthorized` what I get is a `302 Found` redirect.

Since the `Login?ReturnUrl=` will keep appending values eventually the request will throw a query string is too long exception.

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
>
> The request filtering module is
>   configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

https://localhost:44311/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FLogin%....

[image]

In `Web.config` I have disabled `defaultRedirect` and set `customErrors` to `<customErrors mode="Off" />`

```
public class ClientCertificateActionFilter : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
  {
    if (actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
    {
      actionContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "HTTPS Required");
      return;

    }
    else
    {
      X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(actionContext.HttpContext.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);

      if (cert == null)
      {
        actionContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Client Certificate Required");
        return;
      }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a login page or is all authentication done through the cert?

Comment: @Fran There is a login page, however a valid client certificate is needed to view this page. The system contains sensitive information.

Comment: So the user is already logged in (authenticated) using the login page and then additionally needs this cert to view this page?

Comment: @Fran No - a valid certificate is needed to view any page on the server. If you have a certificate you can then login and see the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

I first edited my filter and used `AuthorizeAttribute` with `AuthorizeCore`. My reason for editing was when I tried something that gave an uncaught exception. In this case the user would be authenticated unless I caught the exception and returned `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized` or something similar. However I had to revert my changed code. The reason for this was that Controllers or Methods declared with `[AllowAnonymous]` did not hit the code. The application requires a valid client certificate even to view the login page and therefore I wen't back to `ActionFilterAttribute`.

**Original:**

Looking at the response headers I could see that the response contained the header `www-authenticate: Bearer`.

I then wen't to the file `App_Start` -> `Startup.Auth.cs` to look over the authentication. In `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` and `OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions` I did not see anything strange. However the application also has `app.UseCookieAuthentication` enabled. In here the `CookieAuthenticationOptions` was set to `LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),`. This is what was causing the redirects.

Description for `LoginPath`:

> The LoginPath property informs the middleware that it should change an
>   outgoing 401 Unauthorized status code into a 302 redirection onto the
>   given login path. The current url which generated the 401 is added to
>   the LoginPath as a query string parameter named by the
>   ReturnUrlParameter. Once a request to the LoginPath grants a new
>   SignIn identity, the ReturnUrlParameter value is used to redirect the
>   browser back to the url which caused the original unauthorized status
>   code. If the LoginPath is null or empty, the middleware will not look
>   for 401 Unauthorized status codes, and it will not redirect
>   automatically when a login occurs.

After removing this parameter everything worked.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized` which causes a redirection to the login page. Because the filter is executing each time, it keeps redirecting to itself after it gets there.

What you should return instead is a 403 (`HttpStatusCode.Forbidden`).

Comment: I don't think `Forbidden` is correct in this context. Given that the certificate is not provided I can not authenticate the user and the operation is not forbidden for all users. See the following link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403#Difference_from_status_"401_Unauthorized"

Comment: @Ogglas: You are looking for a certificate. The certificate is not there. You are forbidden from accessing without a certificate. How is that not correct?

Comment: I'm looking for a client certificate to identify a user, not any certificate. 403 should be returned if `Authentication was provided, but the authenticated user is not permitted to perform the requested operation.`. Authentication in this context was not provided since no certificate was sent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_certificate

Comment: @Ogglas: Go do a simple Google search for "403.7 http code" and you will see.

Comment: The point is, you are **not** to return `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized` because you are causing a redirect loop.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did not know about that specific code.

Comment: @Ogglas: No problem. I think MS made up that code because there wasn't a more suitable one out of the [protocol] box. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are extending the wrong part of MVC. MVC has an `AuthorizeAttribute`, which is an `IAuthorizationFilter` that you can extend to put custom functionality such as this. MVC uses HTTP 401 as a *special status* that indicates to redirect to the login page, which is what is returned from the default `AuthorizeAttribute` (and as far as I know there is no way to change this to use a different status code).

The "solution" you found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48446271/) only disables the redirect (not just for your special case, but also for `AuthorizeAttribute`) so when someone tries to access a page that is not allowed, they will get an HTTP 401 response instead of being redirected to the login page (as most users would expect).

Instead of using an action filter, what you should do is add this extra check to a subclass of `AuthorizeAttribute` and then use your custom authorize attribute in place of `AuthorizeAttribute`. Then you can keep the login page in place and it will redirect as expected.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(httpContext.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);

        if (cert == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

If you insist on making this case different than the normal "redirect if not authorized" behavior, you should use a different status code than HTTP 401 for the case of invalid certificate so ASP.NET doesn't hijack the response and turn it into a 302.

Comment: Thanks, after my fix I actually edited the code and used `AuthorizeAttribute` with `AuthorizeCore`. My reason for editing was when I tried something that gave an uncaught exception. In this case the user would be authenticated unless I caught the exception and returned `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized` or something similar.

Comment: I actually had to revert my changed code. The reason for this was that Controllers or Methods declared with `[AllowAnonymous]` did not hit the code. The application requires a valid client certificate even to view the login page and therefore I wen't back to `ActionFilterAttribute`.

Comment: In that case, you should override `OnAuthorization` instead of `AuthorizeCore`. [`OnAuthorization` contains the Reflection scan for `AllowAnonymous`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L94-L95), so if you want to disable it in this special case you need to make that scan conditional. I would suggest copying the entire contents of `OnAuthorization` to your subclass and then edit - do note it contains some additional logic to deal with output caching.